# Exponentiating Rabbits with Recursion and While Loop

Tags: c++

### I asked a question on here a few days ago about this Rabbits program, and I managed to ALMOST finish it. The problem is that when I input 0, it crashes and doesn't run. Can somebody help me out, here is my task:

A pair of newly born rabbits (one male, one female) is put in a field. Rabbits are able to mate at the age of one month so that at the end of the second month each pair produces two new pairs of rabbits and then dies.
Note: In month 0, there are 0 pairs of rabbits. In month 1, there is 1 pair of rabbits.

1. Write a program – using a while loop – that takes the number of months from the user and prints the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
2. In the same cpp file, write a recursive function rabbits() that takes the number of months as input and returns the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
3. In the main program, call the function rabbits() with the number that the user entered. Output both calculations (i.e. the one you obtained with the loop and the one that the recursive function returns) and see if they are equal.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rabbits (int);

int main ()

{
int month_function, month_while, result_rec, result_while, counter = 0, rab_now, rab_lastmonth = 0, rab_twomonthsago = 1;

cout << "Please enter the month. \n\n";
cin >> month_function;
month_while = month_function;
cout << "\n";

if (month_function % 2 == 0) // if month entered is even, the recursive function will use month - 1 because the total number of rabbits doubles every other month
{
    month_function--;
}

result_rec = rabbits (month_function);

while (counter < month_while)
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
    rab_now = rab_lastmonth + rab_twomonthsago;
    rab_lastmonth = rab_now;
    rab_twomonthsago = rab_now;
    }
    counter++;
    result_while = rab_lastmonth;
}

cout << "According to the recursive function, there are " << result_rec << " pairs of rabbits at the end of month " << month_while << "\n\n";

cout << "According to the while loop, there are " << result_while << " pairs of rabbits at the end of month " << month_while << endl;

if (result_rec = result_while)
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "They are equal!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "They are not equal!" << endl;
}

return 0;
}

int rabbits (int month_function)

{
    if (month_function == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (month_function == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       return (rabbits (month_function - 2) + rabbits (month_function - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: just a quick question what is the result of `0 % 2`. Hopefully that might shed some light on the problem

Comment: I fixed the recursion, :D. How can I fix the while loop?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the word problem: is the first pair of babies produced in month 2 or month 3?

Comment: Month 2, I think I fixed it. I initialized both results to be Equal to 0. It fixed everything, I THINK.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
if (month_function % 2 == 0) // if month entered is even, the recursive function will use   month - 1 because the total number of rabbits doubles every other month
{
    month_function--;
}
```

If you enter 0, this evaluates to true, hence `month_function` equals `-1`.

You (most likely) have a bug in your logic as well. If you enter `2` for month function, this will return 0, which is wrong. Think about what answer you should get with an input of 2, it should be fairly easy to fix from there.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter `0` you create a negative number (in the condition `if (month_function % 2 == 0)` is `true` for `month_function == 0`). When then recursively calling `rabbits()` you create a rather deep recursion which will eventually exceed the stack and cause the program to crash. Probably, you don't want to enter the recursion for non-positive values.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter 0, the following expression evaluates to true

```
if (month_function % 2 == 0)
```

So `month_function` is decremented to -1.

Due to the -1, your recursive function `rabbits` never reaches end condition and causes stack overflow.

Comment: I fixed the recursion by adding an "&& month_function != 0" to the if statement to then make an input of 0 false. How can I fix the while loop to properly give me an output for 0?